# Converting IP Address to Hex

Tags: x86, hex

I was wondering how to manually convert an IP address to a hex value on an x86 machine. For example, the book I was reading gives the hex representation of 192.168.42.72 as:

```
    0x482aa8c0
```

but never explains how the conversion works. So, how does it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you convert an IP to a long integer, you take each octet in reverse order and multiply it by `256^n` where *n* is the zero-based reverse index of the octet

So for this ip you're doing

```
(72 * 256^0) + (42 * 256^1) + (168 * 256^2) + (192 * 256^3)
= 3232246344
= 0xc0a82a48
```

It looks like the book is doing it backwards, but you get the idea.

Comment: Also worth noting is that there's a family of functions to do it for you, [inet_aton](http://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_aton) et al

Comment: It's not necessarily doing it backwards, it's probably due to [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) that it comes out the other way

Comment: @DanielDiPaolo Isn't the entire TCP stack spec'd big-endian? Sorry, I know this is a stale question.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you'll see it formatted like this for HEX with IP addresses.

```
 0xC0.0xA8.0x2A.0x48
```

Here's how I do it in my head, because I'm not good with large numbers, since Hex is based 16. The chart below is DEC on left and HEX on right.

```
0 = 0
1 = 1
2 = 2
3 = 3
4 = 4
5 = 5
6 = 6
7 = 7
8 = 8
9 = 9
10 = A
11 = B
12 = C
13 = D
14 = E
15 = F
```

Then once you have the chart memorized, it's just basic math

```
192 = C0 =  (192/16) = 12.0 =  take the remainder (0 x 16) = 0 convert it to Hex (0)      
then take the result (12) divide it by 16 (12/16) and if it's less then 1 then just 
covert the remainder to hex 12 = C then add it up backwards for C0

168 = A8 = (168/16) = 10.8 = he remainder (.8 x 16) = 12.8 convert it to hex (A) then 
take the result (12) divide it by 16 (12/16) and if it's less then 1 then just covert 
the remainder to hex 0 = 0 then add it up backwards for 0A8 or A8

42  = 2A = (42/16) = 2.625 = The remainder (.625 x 16) = 10 convert it to hex (A) then 
take the result (2) divide it by 16 (2/16) and if it's less then 1 then just covert the  
remainder to hex 2 = 2 then add it up backwards for 2A

72  = 48 = Your turn
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't see any powershell answers, so here goes.

This first sample converts IP address to hex.

```
$Octet1 = "{0:X2}" -f 192
$Octet2 = "{0:X2}" -f 168
$Octet3 = "{0:X2}" -f 42
$Octet4 = "{0:X2}" -f 72
$IPAddress = "0x"+$Octet1 + $Octet2 + $Octet3 + $Octet4
$IPAddress
```

Result

`0xC0A82A48`

and this one converts hex back to decimal IP address.

```
$Octet1 = "{0:D}" -f 0xC0
$Octet2 = "{0:D}" -f 0xA8
$Octet3 = "{0:D}" -f 0x2A
$Octet4 = "{0:D}" -f 0x48
$IPAddress = $Octet1 +"."+ $Octet2 +"."+ $Octet3 +"."+ $Octet4
$IPAddress
```

Result

`192.168.42.72`

Answer (score 0):

first convert 192.168.42.72 into binary number as-
11000000.10101000.00101010.01001000
then take 4-4 bits as taken in Binary to Hex number conversion..
so.. 1100 0000. 1010 1000. 0010 1010. 0100 1000
and Hex for this Ip is: C 0. A 8.2 A.4 8
now in accurate Hex representation of IP address.
HEX Code Is:     0xC0A82A48.

easiest method that i know...

Answer (score 0):

```
$ip = "192.168.2.14"
$ar = $ip.Split('.')
$Octet1 = "{0:X2}" -f [int]$ar[0]
$Octet2 = "{0:X2}" -f [int]$ar[1]
$Octet3 = "{0:X2}" -f [int]$ar[2]
$Octet4 = "{0:X2}" -f [int]$ar[3]
$IPAddress = $Octet4 + $Octet3 + $Octet2 + $Octet1
$IPAddress
```