# Convert IP address to 8 digit hex value

Tags: c#, ip, hex

I have an IP "192.168.232.189" and I need to convert it to a hex value "C0A8E8BD" using c#. Can anyone help?

I saw this [Converting IP Address to Hex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581914/converting-ip-address-to-hex) but I'm not entirely sure how to implement that is c#

Thanks

Comment: So you have a `string` with the IP?

Comment: Every 2 hex digits represent a byte. You really just convert the 4 decimal numbers to hex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution for you. First convert the IP address to a number and then get its HEX value. You may want to reverse the HEX to IP, may be in the future, so this link is a [Resource for IP conversions that I use.](http://www.ip2location.com/faqs/db1-ip-country) See output below.

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string ip = "192.168.232.189";
        string ipHexFormat = string.Format("{0:X}", ConvertIpToNumber(ip));

        Console.WriteLine(ipHexFormat);
    }

    public static long ConvertIpToNumber(string dottedIpAddress)
    {

        long num = 0;
        if (dottedIpAddress == "")
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            int i = 0;
            string[] splitIpAddress = dottedIpAddress.Split(new[] { '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            for (i = splitIpAddress.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                num += ((long.Parse(splitIpAddress[i]) % 256) * (long)Math.Pow(256, (3 - i)));
            }
            return num;
        }
    }
}
```

Output
[image]

Answer (score 2):

By using the `IPAddress` class to parse the address (parsing is always the most complex part):

```
IPAddress address = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.232.189");

// Otherwise IPAddress would parse even IPv6 addresses
if (address.AddressFamily != AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
{
    throw new ArgumentException("address");
}

byte[] bytes = address.GetAddressBytes();
string strAddress = string.Format("{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}{3:X2}", bytes[0], bytes[1], bytes[2], bytes[3]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Each piece of the IP address is equivalent to 2 hex digits (or 8 binary digits).
So your problem comes down to splitting up 192.168.232.189 to 192, 168, 232, 189. Then converting each piece (simple decimal-hex conversion) and putting it back together.

Answer (score 2):

If IP address is represented as `String` and you want to have a `String` as a result you can

1. *Split* original string by `'.'` into IP address parts
2. *Convert* each part to `int`
3. *Represent* each part as *hexadecimal* with at least 2 two digits
4. *Concat* all parts together

Possible implementation (*Linq*) is

```
String address = "192.168.232.189";

// "C0A8E8BD"
String result = String.Concat(address.Split('.').Select(x => int.Parse(x).ToString("X2")));
```

Answer (score 1):

here you go

```
string ip = "192.168.232.189";
string hex = string.Concat(ip.Split('.').Select(x => byte.Parse(x).ToString("X2")));
```

- split the ip-string by the `.` with `string.Split()`
- parse each byte with `byte.Parse()`
- convert the `byte` to a hex string `ToString("X2")`
- merge all hex strings together with `string.Concat()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.Net.IPAddress`

```
    IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.232.189");
    Console.WriteLine(ByteArrayToString(ip.GetAddressBytes())); 

public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] ba)
{
  string hex = BitConverter.ToString(ba);
  return hex.Replace("-","");
}
```

Here is [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kJkarK)